# How to make straight lines in d3 tree chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, tree

I have a tree like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/augburto/YMa2y/

I need to change the `diagonal` to `line()` like in the link:
https://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-paths-and-d3js

I tried to make a `step-before` line but it is not working.

How can I do it?